# Как получить только им директории, без полного пути?

Tags: java

Во всех примерах, что я нашел, стандартными методами возможно получить только полные/относительные пути к файлу.
Мне же необходимо знать только имя самой директории, в котором лежит этот путь.
Есть что-то подобное:

```
File file = new File();
file.getPath(); //возвращает C:\Users\Admin\Documents\2020\folder\Файл.pdf
file.getName(); //возвращает Файл.pdf
```

Можно конечно получить путь без имени файла

```
file.getParent(); //возвращает C:\Users\Admin\Documents\2020\folder
```

потом разделить его через `split("\").length();` и взять последний элемент, который будет являться именем директории, в котором этот файл и находится.
(до этого пользовался Pewershell, там при просмотре файла, можно также полностью вывести и имя и свойства этой директории)
Поэтому, может быть и у Java есть все-таки стандартные средства, а не изобретать свой велосипед?

Comment: Посмотри это
Возможно поможет https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009981/getting-the-directory-name-in-java

Comment: поробуйте file.getParentFile().getName();

Comment: @AzizUmarov , вы указали именно то, что нужно. Напишите это как ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Я предлагаю такой вариант

```
String[] r = file.getParent().split("\")
String name= r[r.lenght-1]
```